# A dual Banach algebra question

Tags: banach-algebras

Let $\Gamma$ be an *infinite discrete abelian group* and $A=\ell^1(\Gamma)$ denote its group algebra.
Clearly, $A_*=c_0(\Gamma)$ is a predual of $\ell^1(\Gamma)$ for which $(A,A_*)$ is a dual Banach algebra.

By Matthew Daws' Representation Theorem, there exists a reflexive Banach space $E$ and a weak$^*$ continuous, isometric Banach algebra isomorphism $\phi:A\to B(E)$ onto a subalgebra of $B(E)$ (Corollary 3.8 in [[Daws2007](https://doi.org/10.4064/sm178-3-3)]).

> **Question:** Do we have a simple, explicit relationship between $\Gamma$ and $E$?

In the [same article](https://doi.org/10.4064/sm178-3-3), $E$ was given as an $\ell^2$-sum of the interpolation spaces between $A_*$ and $\mu\cdot A$ for unit-norm $\mu\in A_*$. Here $\cdot$ denotes the convolution.

Perhaps obvious to experts: $E$ does not admit an equivalent uniformly convex norm, since otherwise $B(E)$ (and so all of its subalgebras) would be Arens regular. However, $\ell^1(\Gamma)$ is Arens regular iff $\Gamma$ is finite.

As a side question

> **Question:** Given $\Gamma$, do we have a characterization of reflexive $E$ for which $B(E)$ contains no subalgebra that is isometrically & weak$^*$ isomorphic to $\ell^1(\Gamma)$ ?

Comment: A short (but not uninformed) answer to your first question: NO. (Matt is welcome to correct me, but we have discussed this in the distant past.)

Comment: Regarding the second question: an even earlier result of Daws establishes that B(E) is Arens regular for every super-reflexive E. So certainly if one is given an infinite group Gamma, one knows that the class of E in your question cannot contain any super-reflexive members.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank you for this short but valuable information.